# MACD function in R TTR package giving different result for same dataset

Tags: r, quantmod

I am new to R and trying to develop a back testing strategy using MACD function from TTR package.

I am observing a wired behavior where I get different results for the same data set.

Here are the commands I am executing...

```
# Restarting R session...

library( quantmod )
getSymbols( c('INDRAMEDCO.BO'), from="2016-01-01" )
# [1] "INDRAMEDCO.BO"
macd <- MACD(INDRAMEDCO.BO[, "Adjusted"], 12, 26, 9, percent=FALSE)
last(macd)
#                    macd        signal
# 2016-08-04 3.031666e-317 2.521193e-317
macd <- MACD(INDRAMEDCO.BO[, "Adjusted"], 12, 26, 9, percent=FALSE)
last(macd)
#                    macd         signal
#2016-08-04 4.100941e-317 -2.366901e-318
macd <- MACD(INDRAMEDCO.BO[, "Adjusted"], 12, 26, 9, percent=FALSE)
last(macd)
#                     macd         signal
#2016-08-04 -6.664617e-317 -4.561214e-317
```

Note how MACD and Signal values change on every execution on same data and same parameters to MACD function. I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

Note: I am using RStudio IDE. Not sure if it matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
macd <- MACD(INDRAMEDCO.BO[, "INDRAMEDCO.BO.Adjusted"], 12, 26, 9, percent=FALSE)
last(macd)

                macd    signal
2016-08-04 0.3242379 0.3371936
```

There is not `"Adjusted"` column in the data.

Answer (score 2):

This is one reason that the column extractor helper functions exist (e.g. `Cl`, `OHLC`, `Ad`). I recommend you use them instead of referencing the column directly.

```
R> macd <- MACD(Ad(INDRAMEDCO.BO), 12, 26, 9, percent=FALSE)
R> last(macd)
               macd    signal
2016-08-05 0.346095 0.3387478
```

Comment: Correct @Joshua. This is exactly what I ended up doing :)

Comment: @Programmer: Then perhaps you should consider up-voting and/or selecting this as the answer that best answers the question. See [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).